# Smallest WYSIWG editor you can find?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for the smallest WYSIWG editor i can find.

I have tried TinyMCE, CKEditor etc. but i can not find a small one, all has hundreds of kb js files to load.

I dont need image upload etc, even if i like the one Stackoverflow using so think i need some that more shows like Word but really basic features.

I am using jQuery in the project and i it is a ASP.NET MVC 3.0 project but i really like jQuery and normal html instead of ASP.NET components.

But i am open for ideas about everything that are really basic and tiny size.

Someone has any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smallest one I've found is CLEditor: http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/

Comment: It's also the fastest loading I've found, as it uses a CSS sprite, so the whole toolbar loads at once.

Comment: Press enter and it spits out `<div><br></div>`. That is why I am not a fan of WYSIWYG.

Comment: @Seth I'm not a fan either, but most users have no idea how to use an editor without instructions if it isn't WYSIWYG

Comment: This looks really tiny, going to test it, but its bad with the html output. I going to use it for a discussion forum so not so good. But thats was not my request so good tip!

Comment: Its works good, maybe not the html is really good but its works good and are really tiny code.

Comment: @RickardP There's a bbcode plugin on the page...I used that on a forum I created. Should help with the html quality.

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

```
<p contenteditable="true">Editable text!</p>
```

Admittedly it's not the most fully-featured editor out there, but it's certainly basic and tiny.

Comment: Also quite challenging to use for anything other than pure text.

Comment: @timw4mail: Not true! You can use keyboard shortcuts, eg. Ctrl/Cmd + B for bold.

Comment: that's my point, any additional functionality is non-obvious.

Comment: @timw4mail: Ah, fair enough. It isn't really a viable answer anyway.

Comment: Very interesting none the less.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://www.aloha-editor.org/index.php ?

Comment: About 1MB of JavaScript (currently it requires not only jQuery which would be fine but also ExtJS) is not small. Besides that, it's an awesome editor.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://www.wyzz.info/downloads_page.html

Comment: This is what i am talking about! Looks really basic like i whanted.

Answer (score -1):

Check out TinyMCE.  http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Comment: The OP mentions that he's already tried TinyMCE and it's not suitable.

Comment: Well maybe they didn't try it hard enough.  You strip down almost everything from it

Comment: @Nathan Romano you shouldn't have to trim software down to work for you, you should be able to build on it.

Comment: @timw4mail Why not? That's what customization is.  Slimming the editor down is as easy as making a configuration change.